# AngularJS display first element in array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

Using Laravel for my API and the error response is like this:

[image]

I set that as a scope called errors and do a ng repeat to show them:

```
<ul ng-show="errors" class="list errors-list">
       <li class="item" ng-repeat="error in errors">{{error}}</li>
</div>
```

However, this results in:

```
["The title field is required."]
```

Is there a 'best' way to just get the text and not the speech marks or brackets?

I know I can just search and replace them but always like to know if there is a best way to do something.

Comment: Will Angular let you write `{{error[0]}}`?

Comment: Jeez. Didn't think that would work but should have tried it first. Thanks worked!

Answer (score 1):

Just pull the first element

```
<ul ng-show="errors" class="list errors-list">
       <li class="item" ng-repeat="error in errors">{{error[0]}}</li>
</div>
```

Quoting the [documentation of AngularJS expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression), these are examples of valid expressions in Angular:

```
1+2
a+b
user.name
items[index]    <--- This is what we're using for this answer
```